# Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement a PUSH notification for an app using Firebase Cloud Messaging and cloud functions. The PUSH notification is triggered when a user creates a new order.

The triggering is happening as expected but the cloud function is not completing execution. I am running into an error:

> Exactly one topic, token or condition is required

I have searched online and most possible solutions suggest that this error is triggered by sending an empty FCM token to Firebase, but in my case I have verified that the FCM token is indeed present and valid.

I need help on what other possible causes for this error could be. Here is my code for the cloud function:

```
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
/* eslint-disable max-len */
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
/* eslint-disable indent */
/* eslint-disable no-tabs */
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendOrderNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("pending_orders/{orderId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const orderData = snapshot.data();
        const dinerFCMToken = orderData.dinerFCMToken;
        console.log("Diner FCM token: ", dinerFCMToken);

        const dinerMessage = {
            notification: {
                title: "New Order Submitted",
                body: "Order submitted successfully. Please await confirmation from the restaurant.",
            },
            token: dinerFCMToken,
        };

        try {
            // Send notification to diner
            await admin.messaging().send(dinerMessage);
            console.log("Notification sent to diner successfully");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error sending notification to diner", error);
        }
    });
```

And this is what a sample order object looks like:

```
{
    
"dinerPhone":"254722275885", 
"totalBill":"1700.0", 
"orderId":"BUSI4IP9ZU-231117090130.934", 
"coverDetails":"{1=[OrderItem(menuItem=MenuItem(name=Pilau, description=Spicy rice cooked with beef, price=450.0), isSelected=true), OrderItem(menuItem=MenuItem(name=Fruit Juice, description=Fresh fruit juice, price=150.0), isSelected=true)], 2=[OrderItem(menuItem=MenuItem(name=Chicken Tandoori, description=Grilled chicken with tandoori spice and a touch of chilli, price=850.0), isSelected=true), OrderItem(menuItem=MenuItem(name=Brewed Tea, description=Brewed tea, price=250.0), isSelected=true)]}", 
"dinerName":"Kelvin", 
"orderStatus":"PENDING", 
"dinerFCMToken":"cHT1r9MsR_yzGTLzfmEgdX:APA91bEaczwvAJFEYUbu4rSNrQJtQZZQdPxH5_xskfWjFcNKMXb7bDiL3SRw8M9DtOK-A4AmzwtKI47t0nNRCUf1i60mW3sb8ymJ_WVxAn_Ko3grcNmXQsPQqpfDllfccV17KB0LFMv1", 
"restaurantName":"Blue Lagoon Hotel", 
"bookedDate":"18-Nov-2023 13:00", 
"groupSize":2, 
"restaurantFCMToken":"f8Lh-CdrZAzeDWD4K:APA91bEfPxEXG1Rx1kOyZJN77PD9QiH792KxLKMruozVmsGHENXu8EpolWJUSolOExmkujF12UWRATi4WZjYQL8vbwfIJ-zCfIJX96RCOOP9uXdTCPlW5ToNH7ODVBBNONuA06Io2KAy", 
"orderDate":"17-Nov-2023 09:01"
}
```

I tried generating a new FCM token just in case the one I had was invalid. I created a new one but the problem persisted. I have also tried testing on the Firebase console to see if the problem is with the transmission of the order details, so I basically pasted the order body to the console but that too resulted in an internal server error saying:

> Type error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fcmToken')